# How can I stop the main thread from exiting?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I have this code:

```
5.times do |num|
    puts "Spawning thread ##{num}"
    Thread.new {
        fun
        puts "Thread ##{num} is done"
    }
end
```

`fun` takes quite long to finish, so the main thread has already exited. I know I can use `sleep`, but what if `fun` takes longer than expected? How can I pause the main thread indefinitely without blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation for `Thread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Thread.html), you have to [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Thread.html#method-i-join) the threads:

```
def fun
  sleep 2
end

threads = []
5.times do |num|
  puts "Spawning thread ##{num}"
  threads << Thread.new {
    fun
    puts "Thread ##{num} is done"
  }
end
threads.each(&:join)
```

Output:

```
Spawning thread #0
Spawning thread #1
Spawning thread #2
Spawning thread #3
Spawning thread #4
```

and after 2 seconds:

```
Thread #4 is done
Thread #0 is done
Thread #1 is done
Thread #3 is done
Thread #2 is done
```